# create a certificate for microsoft office using pkcs11 library

Tags: certificate, ms-office, sign, digital-certificate, pkcs#11

I have a PKCS#11 library that contacts with the vendor's smart card. The low level details are not provided and I'm not interested in them either.

BTW the smart card has no internal certificate associated with it, its just a dumb smart card with a private key store.

So my question is:

1. What kind of code should I write to obtain a certificate from the PKCS#11 library, or do I need to write such code? does PKCS#11 supports exporting certificates?(I heard openssl supports using 3rd party PKCS#11 libraries. Can I use that to export a certificate from a smart card?)
2. If the answer to previous question is yes, in what kind of format is the certificate created? What kind of conversions should I to do in order to convert the raw created certificate into office supported format certificate?
3. and the last question is how to apply that certificate into microsoft office(2013) in order to digitally sign documents? It looks like that office itself doesn't like internal certificates and it keeps requesting us to get one from verisign (?) what's wrong here and how can I force office to use my own created certificate using the aforementioned method?

Answer (score 1):

PKCS#11 interface lets you read ("export") the certificate from the hardware. However you need not just a certificate, but also a private key. Most hardware devices won't let you export a private key. PKCS#11 has a set of functions which let you perform cryptographic operations using private keys stored in the hardware, but not to export those keys.

The certificate is usually exported in native DER format, which can later be put to the PFX file. However without a private key it doesn't make sense.

Unfortunately I don't know what MS Office expects. I assume that Office in your case accepts only certificates which can be validated up to the trusted root certificate.

Comment: yes you are right. So in this case I might need to customize the cryptography provider to the custom csp belonging to the smartcard. so basically I need to import pkcs11 cert into Mozilla keystore using custom lib implementation, export it as x509, introduce it to office and then use the custom csp for hashing and signing data. I would be grateful if someone can confirm or correct the concept. maybe I'm missing something here?(how about certificate CA's and how to enroll users into it(?)) unfortunately I don't know much about windows CA and its behavior.

Comment: @lkn2993 I am not sure that the described path is optimal. You can easily extract the x.509 certificate from the PKCS11 device, but what will you do with it next? Custom CSP won't work. The easiest would be to get the CSP for your hardware device, capable to map the certificate to Windows certificate storage. It is assumed that your certificate is issued by the proper CA and that it is for document signing rather than for SSL, for example. If your certificate doesn't match these conditions, then you would probably need another certificate.

Comment: So, if I create my own pki that uses pkcs11 lib and enroll certificate with it, then I would be able to sign office documents. is that it? Well that was a lot simpler than I have initially assumed

Comment: @lkn2993 it depends on whether Office requires a certificate which it can validate. If it does, then you would need to add your root certificate to the list of trusted roots. Also you need to properly set the KeyUsage and ExtKeyUsage properties of the certificate.

Comment: I have no idea about what kind of certificate format office accepts for digital signature, maybe I'm doing something wrong and I would be appreciated if someone helps me with creating and importing a certificate into ms office( it keeps asking me for getting digital ID from verisign everytime(?))

Comment: Well I guess I have figured it out. If you import a pkcs12 file from a file into outlook then you can use it to sign word documents. now there is a new question in mind, that whether I can use a pkcs11 library with non exportable private key to export a pkcs12 file?

Comment: @lkn2993 no,  you can't for the reasons I explained in the answer.

Comment: So the PKI should also act as a sign server? Then how to force ms office to sign using sign server? and also how to implement one? well we know that windows server has internal pki support but I have no idea about setting it up as an office sign server, or did I understand something wrong here?

Comment: "PKI" stands for Public Key Infrastructure. This is an abstract term. It's not clear from your question how it would act.

Comment: From pki I mean a pki application such as XCA or EJBCA

Comment: @lkn2993 I would like to turn your attention that StackOverflow is not a forum but Q&A site. One topic is for one question. I can't keep answering your questions in comments (simply because the SO engine won't let me do this).